# Format number to decimal without rounding

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

I have numbers with decimal values in column,I want to restrict the decimal points to 3 and also want not to round the number.
To restrict the decimal places I used the format cells option.It works fine.But the display value is rounding. I want to stop that

Example

```
Input Value    ExpectValue
345.78976      345.789
```

But in the sheet it display as 345.790

Answer (score 3):

Use `=TRUNC(A1,3)` rather than round.  TRUNC(cell,N) removes all but N decimal places.

Comment: Oh hang on, do you want to format them or actually change the number?

Comment: I want to actually change the number.For example user type the value 345.78976 in cell A1 its should change to the 345.789

Comment: @udaya726 Ok great, then TRUNC is what you need

Comment: Thanks How can I apply to same column user enters the value? For example user type the value 345.78976 in cell A1 its should change to the 345.789

Comment: You could do a cell-validation with `=A1=TRUNC(A1,3)` but then the users gets an error-message if he tries to input something with more decimals (not really user-friendly). Otherwise i think you need to use a different cell for this (like you showed with "Input Value" and "ExpectValue").

Comment: I found another way. You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337008/excel-vba-run-macro-automatically-whenever-a-cell-is-changed). It involves making a VBA-macro which runs after input. With it you can change the input to what you want.